# Automatically reconnecting using `firebase serve` on localhost

Tags: firebase

I am hosting a firebase project on my computer using `firebase serve`. When my internet goes out I get the error below and the program exits. Is there an `--option` that enables auto reconnect or someway to catch the error manually and reconnect? I want the application to keep attempting to connect until my internet comes back online.

```
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
> 
>  Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:firestore.googleapis.com:443
>      at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:328:49)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:304:181)
>      at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:116:74)
>      at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:155:22)
>      at Http2CallStream.endCall (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:141:18)
>      at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:450:14)
>      at ChannelImplementation.tryPick (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\channel.js:237:32)
>      at ChannelImplementation._startCallStream (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\channel.js:267:14)
>      at Http2CallStream.start (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:428:22)
>  Emitted 'error' event on ClientReadableStreamImpl instance at:
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:328:28)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:304:181)
>      [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>      at Http2CallStream.start (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:428:22)
>      at BaseStreamingInterceptingCall.start (C:\Users\Tower\IdeaProjects\team-up-server\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:276:1
9) {
>    code: 14,
>    details: 'Name resolution failed for target dns:firestore.googleapis.com:443',
>    metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
>  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`firebase serve` is deprecated.

Try `firebase emulators:start`; I haven't suffered any on/off/online problems using it.

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup

---

BUT, note in the error message, that the error is related to a Google API call you're making.

If you're calling an online API instead of an emulated one, your app itself will need to be able to be set up to retry or handle failed calls.

Some aspects of firebase can indeed be emulated locally; again, see the docs linked above.

Comment: This actually didn't fix the issue. I thought it did because it emulated the database on my localhost. When i run it like this, `firebase emulators:start --only functions` it still crashes without internet. It is failing when doing `firestore.collection(...).then().catch()` There is a catch, but it is still crashing.

Comment: Please see 2nd part of answer about external API call

Comment: The API is call is made when i call the function like this `firestore().collection(...).get().then().catch()`. The `.catch()` at the end should handle the error, but it is still throwing an error. I also tried wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch block, but that still exits the program.